# mongodb join with different join field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am looking for help for a simple query in mongoDB. I tried but none of them work. When searched mostly the two tables have the same join field or they don't have a condition.

I have two tables say,

1. **Employee (_id, name, deptid, country)**
2. **Department (_id, deptname)**

Now I want to join such as in SQL

```
SELECT employee.name,department.deptname 
FROM employee, department
WHERE employee.deptid = department.id 
AND employee.country = 'India' 
AND department.deptname in ('IT', 'HR')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB allows to "join" two or more collections with `$lookup` operator (SQL `LEFT OUTER JOIN` clause).
In your case, since you want to apply 2 o more conditions, we need to run [multiple join conditions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#perform-multiple-joins-and-a-correlated-subquery-with--lookup)

```
db.Employee.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      country: "India"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Department",
      let: {
        deptid: {
          "$toObjectId": "$deptid"
        }
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            deptname: { $in: ["IT","HR"]},
            $expr: {
              $eq: ["$_id", "$$deptid"]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "Department"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$Department"
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vjhgSpIE54P)

**Note:** if `Employee.deptid` is stored as `ObjectId`, you may use [Correlated subquery](https://mongoplayground.net/p/afZmMicJWls)